# How many different ways are there for five lawyers and seven businessmen to sit around a circular table?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question:**

How many different ways are there for five lawyers and seven businessmen to seat around a circular table, where exactly five businessmen sit together (by together, it means that they sit side by side and there are always two lawyers on their both ends)

**An attempt:**

$$^{7}P_{5}\times^{5}P_{2}\times5!$$

Arranging 5 businessman from 7 businessman, then arranging 2 lawyers from 5 lawyers and then we arrange the rest 5 people in 5! ways

Comment: Are the lawyers and businessmen distinguishable among themselves?  In other words, if we interchange two of the lawyers but make no other changes, is that considered the same arrangement or a different one?

Comment: "Two lawyers on their both ends" means two lawyers at each end ??

Comment: @trueblueanil I think one on each side, so that there are five businessmen in between.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Could be, but as OP had put in the ambiguous phrase, OP should respond

Comment: @trueblueanil Not so ambiguous. If five businessmen sit together, it means there isn't a sixth businessman with them, hence one lawyer (at least) on each side. But let him clarify if it's not clear enough.

Comment: @trueblueanil Actually, my teacher put in the ambiguous phrase. I just copy-pasted his question. He is unreachable at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: @ryang Upvoted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat the table as a clock.  We can always assume the configuration of $5$ businessmen and $2$ lawyers is centered at noon on the clock face, so that the lawyers are positioned at $3$ and $9$.

There are $5$ ways to choose which lawyer is at the 9:00 position.  Once that choice is made, there are $4$ ways to choose the lawyer at the 3:00 position.  Therefore, there are $20$ ways to place the lawyers around the $5$ businessmen.  There are $5! \binom 72=2520$ ways to arrange the businessmen between the lawyers.

Once those choices are made, the remaining $5$ slots can be filled arbitrarily, so there are $5!=120$ ways to do that.

Thus, the answer is $20 \cdot 2520 \cdot 120$ possible configurations that satisfy the constraints.

If rotations are considered different configurations, then multiply that answer by $12$.